# Creating WMS from Pre-existing Cache?

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache

I have preexisting caches of maps that I would like to turn into a WMS. I am trying to implement this through Geoserver/Geowebcache. I tweaked the web.xml file to set the Geowebcache_Cache_Dir to the directory with the preexisting cache. I then put the appropriate information into geowebcache.xml and Geoserver can see the cache under Tile Layers, from here I can open it in OpenLayers, however, I can't ping the cache through a WMS call from arcgis or google earth. I checked the box for direct integration with Geoserver WMS but I still cannot seem to get external softwares to see the WMS. I checked fiddler and it seems to be hitting the tiles in openlayers through /geoserver/gwc/service/wms?blahblahblah. If I try to hit that WMS endpoint from anything else I get the ever so helpful error 400.

Does anyone know the proper method for building a WMS from a cache using this software?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing your config file, is it set up to point the layer to your GeoServer Instance?

Comment: I'm running Opengeo Suite 4.1.1. I can give you all the steps I did to get where I currently am:Tweaked web.xml with 
  <!--Added new GWC Directory-->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
    <param-value>D:\Workspace\Cache\Converted_Cache</param-value>
  </context-param>
Did this to point the cache dir at the folder location with the prebuilt cache (D:\Workspace\Cache\Converted_Cache) cache named “Cache_CADRG_WMS_ARC_Layers”. After reloading Geoserver it places the geowebcache.xml file in that directory.

Comment: I tweaked that geowebcache.xml with   <wmsLayer>
 <name>Cache_CADRG_WMS_ARC_Layers</name>
 <mimeFormats>
  <string>image/gif</string>
  <string>image/jpeg</string>
  <string>image/png</string>
  <string>image/png8</string>
 </mimeFormats>
 <wmsUrl>
  <string>http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms</string>
 </wmsUrl>
 <!--wmsLayers>nurc:Img_Sample</wmsLayers-->
</wmsLayer>

This enabled the tileset to appear under Tile Layers.

Comment: Preview with JPEG in OpenLayers works well but trying to hit the endpoint with ArcGIS (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?) it results in no love. Even with direct integration with GWC enabled and specifying TILED=true it still won't render the tiles in Arcgis/Google Earth etc.

Comment: Have you tried your WMS url with a http:// in front of it? YOu should post your actual Xml file in your question, makes it a lot easier ..

Comment: I attempted to use a standalone instance of GWC and tweaked WEB-INF/geowebcache-wmsservice-context.xml. The line about FullWMS with a parameter set to FALSE, changed it to TRUE.That enabled me to produce a kml network link which works from GE but I still cannot produce a full WMS. I have xml files to attach. @MarkC I appreciate your responses to this. I have config files in a zip file but I can't seem to figure out how to post them to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going back through my questions I wanted to post an update to this that there was a bug at the time that prevented GWC from doing this. I talked directly with the Boundless folks about this at the time. I think it's been fixed since then but haven't tested it since. I ended up working around the issue with a set of cascaded WMSes.